# How to force Windows 8 to render when screen is locked

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-8

I need to capture the screen at regular intervals and I need to be able to do so even if the screen is locked. This wasn't a problem under Windows 7 but Windows 8 seems to behave differently.

For instance the .net function CopyFromScreen throws a Win32 exception when the lock screen is active. I tried also this [excellent example](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/), but it returns black images under windows 8.

It looks like the default behavior in Win8 is to not render at all when the screen is locked.

Would anyone be aware of any way to go around this?

Thanks

Charles

Comment: You may have some luck with [PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869.aspx) if the app you are monitoring supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Sounds like to me like it was a bug in Windows 7 that allowed you to get a screenshot even when the screen was locked. They wised up and fixed it. So now you get black.

Comment: Do you have anything to back that up?